# How to create directory which resembles windows directory

Tags: c++

In Windows we cannot create directory named `con, nul` etc., so `Createdirectory` function is not helping me to create directory with this name.

What can I do to create these directories??

Comment: What for? Why do you want to create a directory with such a name?

Comment: Are you trying to create devices as directories?

Answer (score 1):

CON
PRN
AUX
CLOCK
NUL
COM1
COM2
COM3
COM4
COM5
COM6
COM7
COM8
COM9
LPT1
LPT2
LPT3
LPT4
LPT5
LPT6
LPT7
LPT8
LPT9 are reserved words which can't be normally assigned to files or folders on Windows. While it is not impossible to do so it is **HIGHLY** not recommended

Comment: I'm willing to create an undeletable folder so in order to achieve this I need a folder named con inside my folder what shall I do Thank you

Comment: Don't use "con" as the name, choose another one, and set access rights accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
\\.\\c:\\con
```

This article at wikihow could help http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Folder-Named-Con. The only problem is that when you try to open the folder, the handle will be invalid and you can only delete the file if you type into the command prompt      `rd \\.\\c:\con`. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The names you suggest are not legal file names or extensions in Windows applications.  However, [you can create such names](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html) by [liking your application with Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.msvs-mingw). Presumably you can do this also natively, but I couldn't find an easy way to do this with a quick overview of the Cygwin source code. Note that Windows applications will not be able to access these names.

Comment: I think it's something to do with accessing NTFS through the POSIX namespace or something?